# Show values in a label from chosen item in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a scrpt that I want to show values in a label after post back when chosing an item from dropdownlist. When I choose an item from dropdownlist, for example "Apple", it will show in the label the price of the Apple. And if I choose in the dropdownlist "Orange" in the label it will show the price of the Orange". Any idea how to do this? Thank you.

this is the code...

ContactDetalis.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactDetails.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControl_ContactDetails" EnableViewState="false"  %>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 150px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 294px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
<table class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Klienti:"></asp:Label>
        </td>

        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListKlienti" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Artikulli:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListArtikulli" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListArtikulli_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Cmimi:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelCmimi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="lek"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Sasia:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSasia" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBoxSasia_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Vlera:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelVlera" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="lek"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ContactDetalis.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class UserControl_ContactDetails : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            AddItems();

            //Retain the state of controls
            DropDownListKlienti.Text = Request.Form[DropDownListKlienti.UniqueID];
            DropDownListArtikulli.Text = Request.Form[DropDownListArtikulli.UniqueID];
            LabelCmimi.Text = Request.Form[LabelCmimi.UniqueID];
            TextBoxSasia.Text = Request.Form[TextBoxSasia.UniqueID];
            LabelVlera.Text = Request.Form[LabelVlera.UniqueID];
        }

       if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            AddItems();
        }
    }

    private void AddItems()
    {
        DataTable listaArtikujt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection lidhje = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Artikujt]", lidhje);
                adapter.Fill(listaArtikujt);

                DropDownListArtikulli.DataSource = listaArtikujt;
                DropDownListArtikulli.DataTextField = "Artikulli";
                DropDownListArtikulli.DataValueField = "Cmimi";
                DropDownListArtikulli.DataBind();

                LabelCmimi.Text = DropDownListArtikulli.SelectedValue.ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Gabim:" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownListArtikulli_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItems();
    }
    protected void TextBoxSasia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelVlera.Text = TextBoxSasia.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. What is the problem with your current code? It reads back the entered values. Do you ask how to get the prices, since that isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

remove AddItems(); and add this to your select_changed code

```
protected void DropDownListArtikulli_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelCmimi.Text = DropDownListArtikulli.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```